# Use cases for the Stellar Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, scope

The Stellar Stack Exchange is for developers to ask questions. Asking about protocol, consensus, API, etc. is okay, but **please keep questions not relevant to development (eg trading, business etc) on the slack and the subreddit**.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You (at Stellar) have given that out of your hand when you created a public (contributions licensed by [cc by-sa 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)) Stack Exchange site via the Area 51 site proposal process. This site is not governed by you. The scope of this Stack Exchange site is decided on by the community of this site. Furthermore, there's no need for you (at Stellar) to do anything on this site. Questions ***and*** answers will come from the community. That's why *the community decides what's on-topic.*

By rushing through that proposal phase with the goal of *having a Stack Exchange site* without bothering for the earliest phase there's actually a lot of precedence which gives indication that non-technical questions are very much on-topic.

Have a look at the example questions:

> - How can I contribute to the Stellar project?
> - Who is the Stellar Development Foundation? What are its goals?
> - When is the next Stellar build challenge?

None of those are technical and all of those were questions which where highly voted and made this site a reality.

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a first for our many blockchain sites.

This site 100% absolutely was ***not*** built solely for developer questions. We launched this site based on the description and example questions curated by your community — and that definition very conspicuously includes questions by developers **and end users** in both the description and example questions. This site is expected to live up to that scope we carved out, *comprehensively.*

In all likelihood, if someone proposed a site for "developers of <this platform>", it would have been closed on sight in support of Stack Overflow. See [how to support your developer community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326374/how-can-i-use-stack-overflow-to-support-our-developer-community/326375#326375) to see how that typically plays out. The only reason this site was created was (presumably) the large ecosystem of questions that could not be asked elsewhere. A developer-only site does not live up to that criteria.

So please stop telling end users that their questions do not belong on this site… because without them, this site probably would not have been created.